# How to use magento's native captcha for product review page and contact us form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

In magento 1.7.0.2, a default captcha is available as out-of-box for only some forms like login, registration, checkout as guest only. But I want to use the same captcha for product review form also.

I have seen an extension which adds captcha for product review page, But it looks different from native captcha. If there are different no.of captcha's in one site, it doesnt looks good. So  only I would like to add the native captcha for product review page and contact us page

Answer (score 2):

Install the Product Review Captcha:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/7741.html

If you want to use only one type of captcha, you can install the free Fontis Recaptcha.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fontis-recaptcha.html

Comment: I want to use only magento's default captcha only. The above captchas are differ from the native captcha. So can u please guide me how to use magento native captcha on product review page

Answer (score 1):

Digital Pianism has developped an extension that implements the native Magento captcha on product review forms if you still need it.

You can find it here for now: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/30268/

If the link dies, just google it ;)

Comment: Thanks man! This is just what I needed. Downloaded the extension, then all I had to do is to insert `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` into the review form and to enable captcha for the review form.

Comment: @Zsolti glad it helped you